# How does one pass a quoted list of files on a command line in an MSBuild exec task?

Tags: msbuild

I have a program, let's call it `q.exe`, that accepts a list of quoted paths on the command line. I have an MSBuild item containing files to pass on that command line. How should I pass such a list of files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can turn any MSBuild item into a quoted, space separated string with an item spec similar to the following:

```
@(AnyMSBuildItem->'&quot;%(FullPath)&quot;', ' ')
```

Leading to something like:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <ProcessMe Include="..." />
  <ProcessMe Include="..." />
  <ProcessMe Include="..." />
</ItemGroup>
<Target Name="Build">
  <Exec Command="q.exe @(ProcessMe->'&quot;%(FullPath)&quot;', ' ')" />
</Target>
```

This works by using the `->` syntax to add the quotes, and the `,` syntax to change the separator from the default `;` to a space.